# What is meant by the word "request" in the context of a transient service?

Tags: asp.net-core

Suppose a service meant to be dependency injected (DI) is as follows.

```
    public interface IWorkService
    {
        Task<JobResult> DoWorkAsync(string JobId, 
            JobPostParameters jobParameters,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
    public sealed class WorkService : IWorkService
    {
        private readonly IJobService jobService;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

        public WorkService(
            IJobService jobService,
            IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this.jobService = jobService;
            this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<JobResult> DoWorkAsync(string jobId, 
            JobPostParameters jobParameters,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // omissions...
        }
    }
```

Suppose I intend to register the service as transient.

> Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested
> from the service container.

That quote comes from [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes). In this situation does the "request" constitute construction followed by exactly one method call followed by destruction?  In other words the service object should not contain any private data that survives from one method call to the next?

**Edit**

I am asking about `IWorkService` (not the `IJobService`).

Comment: 'followed by exactly one method call'. Nop..., as long as the object is not out of scope then no new reconstruction of the object. From your sample above, you will get a fresh JobService every time a new WorkService is created. That is all to it.

Comment: @RosdiKasim Sorry I was not clear. I am concerned about WorkService (not the embedded service).

Answer (score 0):

The effective lifetime depends on how `IWorkService` is created / requested from the dependency injection container.

If there is, for example, a singleton `CallerService` which gets a `IWorkService` constructor-injected, that service will use the same `IWorkService` for each call.

On the other hand, if the `CallerService` uses an `IServiceProvider` (for example via an `IServiceScopeFactory`) - each time `GetService` is used to get the `IWorkService` - a new instance will be created.

If the `CallerService` itself is transient-scoped, the question is shifted to who creates that service at which time.

*To sum up, the word "request" describes the act of calling the service provider's `GetService` method (directly or via some helper method). For each such call, a new instance will be created, if the desired service is transient-scoped.*

Comment: My guess is that `GetService` is inside the framework or infrastructure. I think what you're saying is that if a singleton service is holding a transient service then the transient service survives as long as the singleton needs it. Likewise if a "scoped service" is holding the transient service it survives for as long as the entire HTTP request and response pair.

Comment: Yes, it lives as long as you, as a consumer, have a reference to it. New instances are created for each constructor injection or when manually calling GetService on the dependency injection container framework's IServiceProvider.

Comment: I have to add a note about an edge case: the actual "lifetime" may be shorter than the time you have a reference if your IWorkService implements IDisposable. For example if a consuming service implements IDisposable too, its injected services will be disposed with it (for example after a web request has finished). You may also manually dispose your IWorkService but still have a reference. In this case you may have passed the service to some long-living helper (another thread) which then uses the already disposed instance (usually an error).